# Trying to capture IP address from `ifconfig` in terminal

Tags: regex, terminal, grep, ifconfig

I'm trying to come up with a quick command in order to get the IP address of a computer via `grep` and the `ifconfig` command.

So far, I have this `ifconfig eth0 | grep -Eo 'inet addr:[0-9\.]+'` which will return:

`inet addr:192.168.1.26`

I'm trying to adjust the regex though so that I only get the IP address itself. I have very limited knowledge of regex, and I put a non-capturing group around 'inet addr:' which made the command look like this:

`ifconfig eth0 | grep -Eo '(?:inet addr:)[0-9\.]+'`

but that still didn't solve my issue.

Comment: Don't use `ifconfig` on linux, use `ip`. `ifconfig` is deprecated and has been for ages.

Comment: Which OS/distribution and version?

Comment: @EtanReisner My install doesn't have `ipconfig`, do I really gain any benefit with installing it just for this use-case?

Comment: @Cyrus I'm running Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @Zach: Have you this? `hostname -I` ( a large i)

Comment: I didn't say `ipconfig`. I said `ip`. The `ip` binary comes in the `iproute2` package on ubuntu and I expect you already have it installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lookbehind expression; with `grep`, you need to add the `-P` switch to enable this construct instead of `-E` (at least under bash v4.1.1 for cygwin). And so just change a little your last try:

```
ifconfig eth0 | grep -Po '(?<=inet addr:)[0-9\.]+'
```

Comment: Perfect! This solution seemed the most concise so I'm going to use it, but the others are appreciated as well!

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
ifconfig | awk '$1=="inet" && $2!="127.0.0.1"{print $2}'
```

Or on Linux:

```
ifconfig eth0 | awk -F '[ :]+' '$2=="inet" {print $4}'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cut`, to cut output into substrings by delimiter `:`.

```
    ifconfig eth0 | grep -Eo 'inet addr:[0-9\.]+' | cut -d':' -f 2
```

Flag `-f 2` is used to select second substring.